# Nested NavigationFrame in Silverlight App (Multi animation)

Tags: silverlight, navigation, deep-linking

I would like to build a navigation enabled Silverlight app with a slight difference. I don't want to load the entire screen area just a part of it and only in some scenarios.

For example `#/Customer/Cases` loads `/Customer/Cases.xaml` in the entire screen area. But `#/Customer/Cases/Orders` loads `/Customer/Cases/Orders.xaml` in an area where a data grid was displayed (slides to the right maybe).

How do I tell the parent navigation frame not to load the entire #URL but just a part of it? And vis versa for the child navigation frame?

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Please let me know if doesn't make any sense, it's quite hard to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to have two frames.
In the inner-frame you set:

```
InnerFrame.JournalOwnership = JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal;
```

The link `#/Customer/Cases/Orders` loads the page `/Customer/Cases.xaml?Orders` in the outer-frame. The outer-frame than knows it should navigate the inner frame to `/Customer/Cases/Orders.xaml`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Ultimate Framework - Silverlight Navigation Framework that supports unlimited parallel and nested frames with Prism](http://ultimateframework.codeplex.com/)